# Appending to elements in dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes. For each element of the dictionary, I want to append an outside dataframe to the beginning.

```
for x in dict_of_df:
    x = df1.append(x)
```

In this example, `df1` is a dataframe that never changes, and I want to append it to the beginning of every dataframe in my dict of dataframes. However when I do this it doesn't change any elements in the dict, and then returns a random dataframe named `x` with `df1` appended to the beginning. Why won't this "stick" in the elements of the dict?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are iterating through the dictionary you will only get the keys.
give this a try to get to the dataframe values.

I find using .items() is a clean way to handle this.

```
for key, df in dict_of_df.items():
    dict_of_df[key] = df1.append(df)
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, because [`df.append` does not work in-place](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) (in a rather counterintuitive fashion). You need to use `dict.items` to iterate over keys and values, and directly overwrite the value with `d[k] = x`, if you want to see the changes reflected on your dictionary after the iteration.

Comment: yup, this is not gonna change `dict_of_df`

Answer (score 1):

`x` in every loop of your for-loop is key of the dict. Try this

```
for x in dict_of_df:
    dict_of_df[x] = df1.append(dict_of_df[x])
```